# Pass variable from src block to org-edit-src-code

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ess, r

I have a table in org-mode that I want to pass into an R source block and then plot from it. When I write everything in org-mode and execute it, I get the results that I expect.

However, when I enter the ESS editing mode/`org-edit-src-code` by toggling `C-c '` inside the source block, the variable is not used. This is important for complicated scripts where I have to test multiple things and feed multiple variables/tables into the source block.

Here is an example:

```
#+name: test-table
| Cell | Value |
|------+-------|
|    1 |    10 |
|    2 |    20 |
|    3 |    60 |
|    4 |    80 |
|    5 |   100 |

#+name: test-table-plot   
#+BEGIN_SRC R :var test=test-table :results output graphics :exports results :file-ext png
plot(test)
#+END_SRC
```

If I run this source block, I get the plot I expect. If I go into the `org-edit-src-code` with `C-c '` the table "test" does not exist.

Is this meant to be like this? Is there a way to pass the variable to `org-edit-src-code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org-babel expands the src block before sending the contents to R. With `org-babel-expand-src-block` (`C-c C-v v`) you're in the same edit buffer but the code is "expanded".

Comment: Perfect. I just tested it on a more complex example and it worked! Thank you :)